# Confusing operation in c++ program while understanding move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I am trying to grasp the concept of move semantics, rvalues, lvalues in c++ and am facing a problem. I am first looking at this popular answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/9576161

I wrote a small program based on that reply to understand what is going on. I am using `g++` (on linux) and the `-fno-elide-constructors` for compiling without rvalue optimization by the compiler.

Here is the small program:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                      
#include <cstring>                                                                                                                                                       

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                     

class string  {                                                                                                                                                          

    public:                                                                                                                                                              
        char* data;                                                                                                                                                      
        string (const char* p) {                                                                                                                                         
            cout << "Constructor 1 called\n";                                                                                                                            
            size_t size = strlen(p) + 1;                                                                                                                                 
            data = new char[size];                                                                                                                                       
            cout << "this location is: " << this << endl;
            memcpy (data,p,size);
        }

        string (string&& that) {
            cout << "Constructor 2 called\n";
            //cout << "data is " << data << " data location is: " << &data << endl;
            cout << "data location is: " << &data << endl;
            cout << "that.data is " << that.data << " that.data location is: " << &that.data << endl;
            data = that.data;
            that.data = nullptr;
            cout << "this location is: " << this << " data is: " << data << endl;
            cout << "data location is: " << &data << endl;
            cout <<  "that.data location is: " << &that.data << endl;
        }

        ~string() {
            delete[] data;
            cout << "Destructor called for object located at: " << this << endl;
        }

        void print() {
            cout << "String is: " << data << endl;
        }
};

int main () {
    ::string R = "12345";
    cout << "R constructed and located at: " << &R << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On running the program, I see the following result:

```
ubuntu@thinkpad:~/programming_practice/c_projects$ g++ -fno-elide-constructors move_semantics_short.cpp 
ubuntu@thinkpad:~/programming_practice/c_projects$ ./a.out 
Constructor 1 called
this location is: 0x7fffac01bb80
Constructor 2 called
data location is: 0x7fffac01bb78
that.data is 12345 that.data location is: 0x7fffac01bb80
this location is: 0x7fffac01bb78 data is: 12345
data location is: 0x7fffac01bb78
that.data location is: 0x7fffac01bb80
Destructor called for object located at: 0x7fffac01bb80
R constructed and located at: 0x7fffac01bb78

Destructor called for object located at: 0x7fffac01bb78
ubuntu@thinkpad:~/programming_practice/c_projects$
```

Notice the line `data = that.data` in the second constructor (where it says "Constructor 2 is called"). What does it do? Aren't `data` and `that.data` both character pointers? Why is `data` not changing in value? Shouldn't `data` now equal the value of `that.data` which is `0x7fffac01bb80`? Instead it seems like some kind of `memcopy` is occurring and the character string that `that.data` points to is now pointed to by `data`. Any hints on what is going on would be helpful.

Comment: `data` sure better be changing values. It just stole `that`'s `data` and nulls it to prevent accidents a line later.

Comment: You don't need to write an entire class to test what two pointers do when assigned to each other.

Comment: It is so nice to see  `string` as a class name when `using namespace std;` is used as well. Great idea!

Comment: @user4581301 I don't understand. `data` is a character pointer, isn't it? Am I not printing the value of the pointer correctly? I think that is where the problem lies. Instead of `&data`, I think `(void *)data` would `cout` the actual pointer value. Is that right?

Comment: @slava I am using `::`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I believe you are confusing `data` (a pointer) `&data` (a pointer-to-pointer).

Comment: I think I posted this question in a hurry. Should've thought about it a little more before posting. Please delete it if required. To print the value of the pointer I should've typecasted it with `(void *)` instead of `&` which prints the location of `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `&data` is `char**`.  That is, it's the memory location of the pointer that stores the memory location of some `char`.

`data = that.data;` does not make `&data` equal `&that.data`.  It just makes `data` and `that.data` equal.  They now point to the same `char`, but they each exist independently in memory.

If instead of printing `data`'s address, you [print the address *stored in `data`*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71ba3d27969083e8), you can see that you are stealing the array of `char`s that was owned by `that` in your move constructor.